# Flyway migrating successfully but postgres says there are no relations using \dt

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, database-migration, flyway

I'm currently using Docker Compose to setup Flyway to handle table creation and migration.
When all my docker images run, Flyway tells me it successfully validated my migrations but when I check the wallet database and list tables, no relations exist.

Here is my docker compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    container_name: wallet-api-web
    depends_on: 
      - flyway
    ports: 
      - "8080:8080"
  db:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./utils/db.Dockerfile
    container_name: postgres-db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: testuser1234
      POSTGRES_USER: test_user
      POSTGRES_DB: wallet
    image: postgres:13
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: always

  flyway:
    command: -url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/wallet -schemas=wallet -user=test_user -password=testuser1234  -connectRetries=60 migrate
    container_name: flyway-migrations
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: flyway/flyway
    volumes:
      - ./migration:/flyway/sql
```

Here is the dockerfile used to build web.

```
FROM node:15
ENV NODE_ENV=production

WORKDIR /app

COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "./"]

RUN npm install --production

COPY . . 

RUN npm run build

ENTRYPOINT npm run start
```

Here is the Dockerfile used to build the database image.

```
FROM postgres:latest

ENV POSTGRES_DB wallet

COPY ../init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Here is the init file used by the postgres image.

```
CREATE USER test_user;
CREATE DATABASE wallet;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE wallet TO test_user;
```

Here is my migration file:

```
CREATE TABLE wallet.transaction_events (
    transaction_version int,
    transaction_type VARCHAR(200),
    coins int,
    transaction_id VARCHAR(500),
    wallet_id VARCHAR(500) PRIMARY KEY
)
```

This is my current file structure (directories use - and files use +)

base directory

```
- migration 

    - sql

        + V1__transaction_events.sql

- utils

    - db.Dockerfile

+ Dockerfile

+ init.sql

+ docker-compose.yml

+ package-lock.json

+ package.json
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated as i'm new to docker and flyway and this has been stumping me for awhile. If any follow up information is required ill be sticking around so feel free to ask. Thank you again.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your actual migration, but I'm guessing that the migration put the tables in a schema that is not in your search path.

Comment: @Jeremy, just updated the post with my migration file. Didn't intend to leave it out.

Comment: Are you just typing \dt or \dt wallet.*?  I also wonder if there's an issue due to the missing ; at the end of the migration.

Comment: you should add a locations parameter to your flyway command with the location of the sql files